# Uncertainty of a least squares fit with uncertain data

Tags: least-squares, fitting, measurement-error, uncertainty

I often find myself with questions that vary along this theme, but the internet is so full of simpler cases that I can never find what I'm looking for. So this question is two-fold: a) what's the answer? and b) what books should I have read / terms should I have googled to have answered this myself? So:

I have measurements at a few points $x_i$ resulting in measurements $y_i$ with standard uncertainties $\sigma_i$ (assume no uncertainty in $x_i$ for now). I know that these points should lie on a straight line, so I perform a least-squares fit, weighted by $1/\sigma_i^2$, giving me $y = m x + c$.

*Question 1:* What's the uncertainty on $m$ and $c$? Matlab, R, Excel etc will tell me the fitting uncertainty, but this ignores the measurement uncertainty.

*Question 2:* What's the uncertainty of $y(x \neq x_i)$, i.e. a the value of this function for a point that I didn't measure?

*Question 3:* What if this was instead a 2nd order polynomial? An exponential? Some horrible non-linear function? Etc.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: It seems to me like splitting these up wouldn't make much sense: they're very related and I'd have to give all the background over again

Comment: If you go to the "Errors-in-variables models" entry on Wikipedia I think you will find what you are looking for, or at lease a good start.

Comment: @Thomas Fantastic, a quick look makes me think that's just the pointer I needed